# How to set a dynamic var before aot compile

Tags: clojure

I want to have a `*flag*` variable in a given namespace that is set to `true` only when `:aot` compiling.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried combinations of testing `*compile-files*` and using `alter-var-root`?

Comment: I just did. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is kind of complicated because the definition of Clojure's own dynamic nature, so there's no rough equivalent of C's `#ifdef` or some other mechanism that happens at compile time, but here's a workaround:

I created a Leiningen project with `lein new app flagdemo`. This trick detects when AOT is performed, as @Biped Phill mentioned above, using the dynamic var `*compile-files*`, and saves a resource in the classpath of the compiled code:

The code looks like this:

```clj
(ns flagdemo.core
  (:gen-class))

(def flag-path "target/uberjar/classes/flag.edn")

(defn write-flag [val]
  (try (spit flag-path (str val)) (catch Exception _)))

(defn read-flag []
  (some-> (clojure.java.io/resource "flag.edn") slurp clojure.edn/read-string))

(write-flag false)

(when clojure.core/*compile-files*
  (write-flag true))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (println "Flag is" (read-flag)))
```

So, when the file *loads* using, say, `lein run` or when you load it in the REPL, it will try to write an EDN file with the value `false`.

When you compile the package using `lein uberjar`, it loads the namespace and finds that `*compile-files*` is defined, thus it saves an EDN file that is packaged with the JAR as a resource.

The function `read-flag` just tries to load the EDN file from the classpath.

It works like this:

```
$ lein clean
$ lein run
Flag is nil

$ lein uberjar
Compiling flagdemo.core
Created /tmp/flagdemo/target/uberjar/flagdemo-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Created /tmp/flagdemo/target/uberjar/flagdemo-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar

$ java -jar target/uberjar/flagdemo-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
Flag is true
```

Comment: Wow. that's cool. Would you know when the *compile-files* var kick in? Is it only on :aot compile or does it get set to true when doing C-c C-k on the emacs buffer?

Comment: Okay, it's false for C-c C-k on emacs.

Comment: yeah, that's because C-C C-k is bound to cider-load-buffer that just loads the file

Answer (score 2):

Credit to @Biped Phill and @Denis Fuenzalida for explaining it to me.

I think this works as well:

```
(def ^:dynamic *static* false)

(when (and *compile-files* boot/*static-flag*)
  (alter-var-root #'*static* true))
```

then in `profiles.clj`:

```
:injections [(require 'boot)
             (intern 'boot '*static-flag* true)]
```

Comment: `alter-var-root` is documented as `(alter-var-root v f & args)`.  In other words, it works like `swap!`.  Bottom line, `#(constantly true)` instead of `true`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to indicate that a variable will change over time:

```clj
(def ^:dynamic *the-answer* nil)
*the-answer*
;=> nil
```

The `^:dynamic` bit will allow that variable to be rebound later:

```clj
(binding [*the-answer* 42] *the-answer*)
;=> 42
```

---

**ADDENDUM 1**

Here's what would happen if you didn't use `^:dynamic`:

```clj
(def *the-answer* nil)
(binding [*the-answer* 42] *the-answer*)
;=> [...] Can't dynamically bind non-dynamic var [...]
```

**ADDENDUM 2**

These kind of variables are commonly referred to as ["earmuffs"](https://cljs.github.io/api/syntax/earmuffs). The naming convention is unenforced but strongly encouraged.

Here's what happen in the REPL when you use this naming without declaring a dynamic variable:

```clj
(def *the-answer* nil)
; Warning: *the-answer* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *the-answer* or change the name. (/tmp/form-init7760459636905875407.clj:1)
```

Comment: `binding` doesn't generally do anything at the namespace scope when AOT compiling, It establishes runtime bindings, which are not interesting while compiling. In particular, `(binding [*the-answer* 42] (defn f [] *the-answer*))` compiles a function that returns nil.

Comment: @amalloy To be honest I wasn't sure whether the question was more about how to do dynamic variables in general than this specific case of which the intricacies have completed escaped me. Thanks for the info though; do you reckon I should just delete this answer? It doesn't seem very useful now.