# What is the use case of *compile-files* in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm reading lots of Clojure code and see some interesting things (at least for me). [Here is some code that I encountered](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/blob/981acc654db00435bf73ad7ac9a24a2ce56ca883/src/metabase/logger.clj#L40):

```clj
(when-not *compile-files*
  (.addAppender (Logger/getRootLogger) (create-appender)))
```

Why/when would you use this dynamic binding ***compile-files*** ?

Comment: Add a link to where you saw it?

Comment: @AlanThompson added into "Here is some code that I encountered" text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This binding is set from `compile`.  The way the compilation works with
Clojure is to basically "run" NS to compile for its *top level side
effects* in regard to where Clojure puts things (e.g. `ns`, `defn`,
`def`, ...) and store the results as `.class` files.

This also means, that if your code contains "real side effects" at top
level, they will be executed at compile time too, which usually
surprises people.

So if you have "dangerous" things you want to do once the ns loads, you
can protect from execution at compile time by checking for
`*compile-files*`.

There are other means to "hide" things from the compiler.  E.g. a common
usecase is to use `delay` for `def`s that trigger side effects like
creating a database connection.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of cases that I can think of:

- Running some code at compile (AOT) time to produce certain artifacts, as in this question: [How to set a dynamic var before aot compile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60647682/483566)
- Ensure that the `require` doesn't result in AOT'd class files, as in this [example from ClojureDocs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/*compile-files*#example-5e6fbf90e4b087629b5a18bf).